# ADB screencap while playing video

Tags: android, adb, screen-capture

```
adb exec-out screencap -p > screen.png
```

This used to work on my Chromecast with Google TV while playing video (no DRM) when it was running on Android 10. After upgrading to Android 12, it just produces a completely white image (with correct screen resolution; with no other view widgets either). This is the case when playing videos using MX Player, YouTube and other apps using ExoPlayer.

Can I get `screencap` to work as it did or another way to take screenshots?

Comment: Wondering if [scrcpy](https://github.com/Genymobile/scrcpy) works on your device or not.

Comment: Once the video starts, scrcpy shows a flickering image of the last thing on screen before the video started.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't be done. Blocked on an OS level.

Answer (score 0):

It depends very much on the app and how it plays the video. Youtube screenshots white it's playing a video can be obtained using [AndroidViewClient/culebra](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient)'s `dump`:

```
dump -Df ~/tmp/myyoutubescreenshot.png
```

produces something like this (scaled to 25% to be able to upload it here):

[image]

Youtube app version might also be considered. Anyways, it's easy to try if it works on your cases and/or devices.